# Webview with HTTP authentication

Tags: android, authentication, webview, sdk

I used a webview to acces a site with http authentication by using the url formant:
http://username:password@url.com. On some 4.4 devices im logged in on some other jellybean ones i am not. What can i do?
p.S.: i cant choose older target sdk in the avd manager although i downloaded some

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    Bundle icicle = null;
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
    //String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    //if (restoredText != null) 
    //{
      //mSaved.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
      //long name = prefs.getLong("name", -1);
      //long pw = prefs.getLong("pw", -1);
      /*if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1)
      {
         mSaved.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
      }*/
    //}





    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoJavaScriptInterface(), "demo");


   // mWebView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(url", "", "usr", "pw");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                  view.loadUrl(url);
                  return true;
                   }}); 

    mWebView.loadUrl("//here url stuff");
    //return false;


    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    MenuInflater inflater1 = getMenuInflater();
    inflater1.inflate(R.menu.reload, menu);



    return true;


}






final class DemoJavaScriptInterface {

    DemoJavaScriptInterface() {
    }


    public void clickOnAndroid() {
        Handler mHandler = null;
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:wave()");
            }
        });

    }
}

//chrome
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private final String LOG_TAG = null;

    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you dont need to setContentView in onCreateOptions menu better to move that webview code into onCreate metot

Did you check logcat maybe you are getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` cuz you are trying to do some request in onCreateOptionsMenu method

Comment: logcat didnt say sth like that